# How to use py2exe with third-party libraries

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a Python script that uses ClientCookie and ClientForm. I need to create an executable file via py2exe, so I placed "ClientCookie" and "ClientForm" inside the script's directory and create file named "setup.py" with the following content:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console = ['some_script.py'],
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'packages': ["ClientCookie", "ClientForm"]  
        }
    }
)
```

When I've tried to create an executable file, it gives me the following error:

```
> setup.py py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\projects\some_project\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    'packages': ["ClientCookie", "ClientForm"]
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1306, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(f)
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "E:\software\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named ClientCookie
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing "ClientCookie" and "ClientForm" in your scripts directory, follow these steps-

**1.** Place them in the "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" directory (this is the default directory where 3rd party libraries are installed into). Also, it seems that you have created these packages manually so double check them for dependency issues.

**2.** Place your main python script and the setup.py script in the python root folder i.e., "C:\Python27" in my case.

**3.** Run setup.py

**Note:** If you still face the same problem then try removing both python and py2exe completely and then re-installing both.